# React JSX working without importing React

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to run my first React JSX file and it works! However, I don't have these two import statements included in my JSX:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
```

I thought I would need these two imports so that when the JSX was transpiled to JS (by `React.createElement`), the React component would be in scope. But it seems to work even without the two imports.

How is it that this works without the imports?

Here is my code:

script.jsx:

```
var Main = React.createClass({
    getIntialState: function () {
        return {
            counter: 0
        };
    },
    clickHandler: function () {
        return {
            counter: this.state.counter + 1
        };
    },
    render: function () {
        return (
            <button onClick={this.clickHandler}>+2</button>
        )
    }
});
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "reactjs",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "react.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "webpack": "^1.13.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.18.2",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.8",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
    "react": "^15.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
   "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
   "dev": "webpack --watch",
   "build": "webpack -p"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

HTML file

```
<html>
<head>

    <title>
        !My first React JS Component!
    </title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="react.js"></script>
    <script src="output.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    entry: "./app/script.jsx",
    output: {
        filename: "output.js"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader'
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: You are probably using the file in a global scope with `<script>`. How is your project built ?

Comment: I've a script tag in my HTML file like <script src="output.js"></script>. My project is built using webpack bundle which use babel-loader

Comment: What are the contents of `react.js`? Is that a copy of the React library?

Comment: Okay, I think I found it myself. It's because I have included react.js in my script tag as @DorWeid has pointed out. So it works even without the import. thanks all and sorry to be dumb!

Comment: Yes, it's the copy of the react library :-) That explains it. Sorry and thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because I have included react.js in my script tag as @DorWeid has pointed out. So it works even without the import. thanks all and sorry to be dumb!