# How to avoid importing react in every main file?

Tags: reactjs

I am using VSCode and in official docs as well as many videos I have seen that we do not have to always `import React from 'react'` but if I try doing that it just throws an error and I have to add it eventually. I have the latest version of React as you can see below but not getting what exactly is the issue here.
I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40950537/react-jsx-working-without-importing-react?rq=1) answer but it is also not working for some reason.

Here is my package.json:

```
"react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "^1.1.5",
```

Here is the console log:

```
'React' must be in scope when using JSX  react/react-in-jsx-scope
```

For instance this is Home.jsx:

```
import './home.scss';

const Home = () => {
    return <div className='home'>Hello</div>;
};

export default Home;
```

Comment: Can you publish the code of your react component?

Comment: You can remove that lint rule

Comment: @abdou-tech check, updated

Comment: I didn't get you @RajendranNadar

Comment: Ask yourself why you need to import it. (hint: it's line 4 of your example)

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64541040/jsx-can-be-used-without-importing-react) shows that I do not need to do the ESLint rule, but that is not working either. It is throwing the same error.